# how to select specific json element in python

Tags: python, json

I can't figure out how to select a specific element in a JSON object, and I cant come up with a search phrase to google.

This is my JSON

```
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "category": {}
  },
  "totalResultSize": 209,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "1000004006560322",
      "ean": "0828768235928",
      "gpc": "music",
      "title": "title",
      "specsTag": "tag",
      "summary": "summary",
      "rating": 45,
      "urls": [
        {
          "key": "DESKTOP",
          "value": "http://www.url.com"
        },
        {
          "key": "MOBILE",
          "value": "https://m.url.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how can I select the URL where the key is MOBILE?

thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Please copy-paste the exact JSON text you are working with.

Comment: First of all, that's not valid JSON. You can use json module which will load it as a dict.

Comment: Have you read the python manual? In the docs this info is easy to find.

Comment: sorry guys, new JSON included

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as duplicate, the question is quite different. The ref question asked how to get the value, when you know the key. This one is more like "select object from list where key= value".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- First, convert your JSON document into a python object using `json.loads` or `json.load`
- Second, loop through the "urls" dictionary looking for the item in question

For example:

```
import json

json_document='''
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "category": {}
  },
  "totalResultSize": 209,
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "1000004006560322",
      "ean": "0828768235928",
      "gpc": "music",
      "title": "title",
      "specsTag": "tag",
      "summary": "summary",
      "rating": 45,
      "urls": [
        {
          "key": "DESKTOP",
          "value": "http://www.url.com"
        },
        {
          "key": "MOBILE",
          "value": "https://m.url.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
'''

python_obj = json.loads(json_document)

for url in python_obj["products"][0]["urls"]:
    if url["key"] == "MOBILE":
        value = url["value"]
        break
else:
    # Some default action
    print "No url found"
    value = "http://www.url.com"

print "Value:", value
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I believe should do the trick.

```
first = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3,, "d": 4, "e": }
second = {"b": 3, "c": 4, "d": 5, "e": 6, "f": 7}
values = {"a","b","c"}
first.update((key, val) for (key, val) in second.items() if key in values)
```