# How to turn a complicated json into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm pulling FRED data through their api and I'm getting complicated JSON back.  Buried in this data is liability data.  Inside the JSON, is a nested 'observations' key and inside of that key is a list of dictionaries with 'date' and 'value' keys.  I need the date and value as the column headers.  Date could also be the index.

To get the data, one will need a free api key found here:  https://fred.stlouisfed.org/.  Just go to my account and follow the instructions.

For the code to pull the data, see the below.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import urllib
import requests
from fred_api import fred_api #config file with my personal api
networth_endoint = r'https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred/series/observations?series_id=BOGZ1FL102090005A&api_key={}&file_type=json'.format(api)

content = requests.get(url = networth_endoint)

data = content.json()
data
```

If you don't want to go through that hassle, below is a snippet of what is returned:

```
{'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
 'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
 'observation_start': '1600-01-01',
 'observation_end': '9999-12-31',
 'units': 'lin',
 'output_type': 1,
 'file_type': 'json',
 'order_by': 'observation_date',
 'sort_order': 'asc',
 'count': 74,
 'offset': 0,
 'limit': 100000,
 'observations': [{'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1945-01-01',
   'value': '215967.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1946-01-01',
   'value': '232012.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1947-01-01',
   'value': '269729.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1948-01-01',
   'value': '294148.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1949-01-01',
   'value': '304352.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '1950-01-01',
   'value': '328550.0'}...

{'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '2017-01-01',
   'value': '15479906.0'},
  {'realtime_start': '2020-03-03',
   'realtime_end': '2020-03-03',
   'date': '2018-01-01',
   'value': '16491618.0'}]}
```

This goes one from 1945 to the last reported quarter.  Actual json broken up by `...`

Can anyone figure out how to pull each date and value out of the json and make a dataframe with it?

Comment: this should help: [how to select a specific element in a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483655/how-to-select-specific-json-element-in-python)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't get me what i want.

Comment: so you've tried `json.loads`?

Comment: yes.  When i pull the content from the URL, it pulls it in as a dict.  I think I just figured it out:  `for i in data['observations']: 
 print(i['date'], i['value'])`